# Random number generator baseball

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

From the HMMT competition here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/hmmt-archive/november/2017/HMMTNovember2017ThemeRoundSolutions.pdf

> New this year at HMNT: the exciting game of RNG baseball! In RNG baseball, a team of infinitely many people play on a square field, with a base at each vertex; in particular, one of the bases is called the home base. Every turn, a new player stands at home base and chooses a number $n$ uniformly at random from $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Then, the following occurs:
>
> - If $n > 0$, then the player and everyone else currently on the field moves (counterclockwise) around the square by $n$ bases. However, if in doing so a player returns to or moves past the home base, he/she leaves the field immediately and the team scores one point.
> - If $n = 0$ (a strikeout), then the game ends immediately; the team does not score any more points.
>
> What is the expected number of points that a given team will score in this game?

Here's what I did. Let $p_i$ denote the probability that a player on base $i$ scores a point before the game ending. We have the system of equations:
$$p_0 = {1\over5}(p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + 1), \quad p_1 = {1\over5}(p_2 + p_3 + 2), \quad p_2 = {1\over5}(p_3 + 3), \quad p_3 = {4\over5}$$Solving for $p_0$ gets us ${{409}\over{625}}$. Therefore, I find the desired expected value to be$${{409}\over{625}}\left(\left({4\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right) + 2\left({4\over5}\right)^2\left({1\over5}\right) + 3\left({4\over5}\right)^3\left({1\over5}\right) + \ldots\right) = {{1636}\over{625}}$$However, this is wrong because the answer in what I linked above is ${{409}\over{125}}$, which they got via computing:
$${{409}\over{625}}\left(1 + \left({4\over5}\right) + \left({4\over5}\right)^2 + \left({4\over5}\right)^3 + \ldots\right) ={{409}\over{125}}$$So what did I do wrong? What accounts for the discrepancy?

**Update:** Let me explain my reasoning for how I got: $$\left({4\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right) + 2\left({4\over5}\right)^2\left({1\over5}\right) + 3\left({4\over5}\right)^3\left({1\over5}\right) + \ldots$$For the first term, there's a ${4\over5}$ chance of not ending the game on the first turn and a ${1\over5}$ chance of ending the game of the second turn. For the second term, there's a ${4\over5}$ chance of not ending the game on the first turn, a ${4\over5}$ chance of not ending the game on the second turn, and a ${1\over5}$ chance of ending the game of the third turn. Etc.

Comment: Expected score every turn is $\cfrac{409}{625}$. Now there is a $\cfrac{4}{5}$ chance every turn that the game continues and hence $(1 + \cfrac{4}{5} + \cfrac{4^2}{5^2} +...)$ and the answer is $\cfrac{409}{125}$. I am not clear on the geometric series you are setting up.

Comment: @MathLover I have edited in an explanation for the geometric series I set up. Also, I don't know how you get $1$ as the starting term in your geometric series, given that there is a ${4\over5}$ chance of the game continuing on the first turn.

Comment: OK I read now but you are multiplying by $2$ if it is second turn, by $3$ if it is third turn. That should not be the case. Look at it this way: what is the score you make in the first turn? $\frac{1}{5} \cdot 0 + p_0$, $p_0$ should not again be multiplied by $\frac{4}{5}$ in the first turn because probability of getting $1, 2, 3, 4$ are all included in the working already. Now the probability that there is a second turn is $\frac{4}{5}$ and again expected score in second turn is $p_0$, probability there is a third turn is $\frac{4^2}{5^2}$ and expected score in third turn is again $p_0$...